# Installing WKHTMLTOPDF on AIX

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Does anyone know if I can install `wkhtmltopdf` on AIX? I know I can do it in Linux, MacOS and Windows but I don't know if I can do it on AIX.

Comment: Wow, I would love to test this but sadly there aren't any AIX machines laying around and I dont think it's possible to virtualize AIX using something like VirtualBox. Good question.

Comment: Well I am working for a client and was trying to build it from source yesterday. The source code for the 0.9.9 version does not seem to have a make file!! and I could not git clone the repository as the AIX version I had did not have git installed. Waiting for the sysadmin to grant me root rights, so that I can install GIT and then build it. If no one answers, I will update this question with my experience.